# Adding space between triangle nodes in separate levels in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I now switched to `tikz-qtree` and want to add more space between the two triangle nodes. I cannot figure out a way to do this, since the nodes are on different levels.

Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=4\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=16\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
          {\sc comps} { },\\
          {\sc cont} {4}]\\
          \end{tabular}}
          [.{{1} NP{5}} man ]
          [.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
               {\sc comps} { 1 },\\
               {\sc cont} {4}]\\
               \end{tabular}}
               [.{{2} NP{6}} \edge[roof]; ketābāro ]
               [.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
                   {\sc comps} { {1}, {2} },\\
                   {\sc cont} {4}]\\
                   \end{tabular}}
                   [.{{3} PP{7}} \edge[roof]; {be Sepide} ]
                   [.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
                        {\sc comps} { {1} NP{5}, {2} NP{6}, {3} PP{7}},\\
                        {\sc cont} {4} give({5}, {6}, {7})]\\
                        \end{tabular}} dādam ]
               ]
          ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing between the the triangles is determined by the width of the nodes that dominate them.  You can wrap any node label in an explicit TikZ `\node` command and then specify a minimum width for the node.  This will add some padding around the node and therefore increase the space between its daughters.

See [How do I center this qtree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44472/2693) for a similar problem.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=4\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=16\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
          {\sc comps} { },\\
          {\sc cont} {4}]\\
          \end{tabular}}
          [.{{1} NP{5}} man ]
          [.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
               {\sc comps} { 1 },\\
               {\sc cont} {4}]\\
               \end{tabular}}
               [.\node[minimum width=2cm] (N) {{2} NP{6}}; \edge[roof]; ketābāro ]
               [.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
                   {\sc comps} { {1}, {2} },\\
                   {\sc cont} {4}]\\
                   \end{tabular}}
                   [.{{3} PP{7}} \edge[roof]; {be Sepide} ]
                   [.{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
                        {\sc comps} { {1} NP{5}, {2} NP{6}, {3} PP{7}},\\
                        {\sc cont} {4} give({5}, {6}, {7})]\\
                        \end{tabular}} dādam ]
               ]
          ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]