# Restoring qtree spacing in tikz-qtree

Tags: spacing, trees, tikz-qtree, qtree

Is it somehow possible to achieve the same node spacing in `tikz-qtree` as in the original `qtree` package? Compare the two:

qtree:

[image: qtree]

tikz-qtree:

[image: tikz-qtree]

The spacing between nodes in one level should be the same. Also, I somehow dislike that the lengths of the edges are depending on the content (see the dot vs. Z).

The reason I use `tikz-qtree` is because I have a tree which has a node with more than 5 branches, which `qtree` doesn't support.

Edit: And the tree code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
% or \usepackage{qtree}

\newcommand{\bftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\bftt{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \Tree [.$Z$ \ts{(} [.$Z$ \ts{.} [.$Z$ \ts{(} [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] \ts{)} [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] ] ] \ts{)} [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a document with the tree so we can play?

Comment: Oh, of course, totally forgot that.

Comment: `\tikzset{sibling distance=2pc}`, for instance

Comment: That's not working, tikz-qtree still adjusts the spacing. It just gets wider in total.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to replicate `qtree` spacing in `tikz-qtree` since the latter package uses a completely different method for node spacing; most of the time this leads to much better looking trees, especially for linguistics, which was its intended use. You can balance out particular node manually by enclosing their contents in an explicit `\node` command and specifiying a width.  The imbalance comes from having very different widths dominated by by the nodes at the first level.  See [How do I center this qtree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44472/2693) for a similar problem. For the node size problem, I've used egreg's `\phantom` solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}


\newcommand{\bftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\bftt{#1}\protect\vphantom{$A$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \Tree [.$Z$ \node[minimum width=1cm]{\ts{(}}; [.$Z$ \ts{.} [.$Z$ \ts{(} 
    [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] \ts{)} [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] ] ] \node[minimum width=2cm]
    {\ts{)}}; [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of tikz-qtree code]

### A solution using the `forest` package

The recent [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) package provides the tools to do this fairly easily. Although its main *raison d'être* is to make more compact trees, it provides hooks to make less compact trees too.  The input syntax is a bit different: there are no `.` to mark node labels, and terminal nodes *must* be enclosed in `[ ... ]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand{\bftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\bftt{#1}\protect\vphantom{$A$}}

\begin{document}
\forestset{qtree edges/.style={for tree={
parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}}}

\begin{forest}
[$Z$, qtree edges,s sep=1cm [\ts{(}] [$Z$ [\ts{.}] [$Z$ [\ts{(}] [$Z$ [$\epsilon$] ]
[\ts{)}] [$Z$ [$\epsilon$] ] ] ] [\ts{)}] [$Z$ [$\epsilon$] ] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but I really don't want to do this manually for tens of trees. `anchor=north` seems to place the dot too high.

Comment: @neo On the centering issue of the dot, try `anchor=center` then.

Comment: But then the original problem with the different edge lengths reappears. egreg posted a workaround for this using phantom.

Comment: The main problem with `tikz-qtree` is the case of three branches. Then, often the middle edge isn't straight and doesn't look right.

Regarding `forest`, the leaves shouldn't overlap each other, so that's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @neo You're using tools designed for linguistics for another purpose, so you're likely going to have to make some compromises. Both `tikz-qtree` and `forest` improve the spacing for linguistics by making more compact trees. The `forest` package provides you with complete control over the spacing, so I would go with that. You can add more separation to any of the nodes in the example I posted.

Comment: Well, if you got space problems, then yes, it's definitely an improvement using `tikz-qtree` or `forest`, but especially for small examples it would be nice to have an option (in `tikz-qtree`?) for geometrically nice node spacing as in `qtree`.

Comment: I was a bit busy in the last days, so @AlanMunn beat me with the answer using `forest` --- thanks Alan! I'd like to add that I'm just developing (yet) another hook which will make it relatively easy to implement even spacing (among other things). It should be ready in a week or so. I'll post an answer when it is.

Comment: Another thing: check out [Is it possible to emulate qtree with forest?] for syntax-level compatibility between `qtree` and `forest`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of `tikz-qtree` mentions the key `sibling distance`; you can set it globally with, say,

```
\tikzset{sibling distance=1pc}
```

in the preamble or locally for a particular tree with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=1pc]
\Tree [...]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For the height of the nodes, I suggest to put a phantom in the definition of `\ts`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newcommand{\bftt}[1]{\textbf{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\bftt{#1}\protect\vphantom{$A$}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=1pc]
\Tree [.$Z$ \ts{(} [.$Z$ \ts{.} [.$Z$ \ts{(} [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] \ts{)}
  [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] ] ] \ts{)} [.$Z$ $\epsilon$ ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the phantom, but the spacing is still different? In `qtree` you can see that all four nodes of level 1 are exactly separated by the same amount of space.