# Alignment with tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

When using labels with different lengths with `tikz-qtree`, tree nodes are sometimes not aligned. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[text depth=0pt]
        \Tree [.{a}
            [.{b}
                [.{d} ]
                [.{e} ]
                [.{ffffff} ]
            ]
            [.{c}
                [.{g} ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Just as `c` and `g` are aligned, I'd like to make the edge between `b` and `e` go straight down; I do realize that this way, the horizontal space between the the child nodes elements will be different, but this I find less annoying than the angles leaving a node not lining up correctly :).

[image]

Comment: This is how `tikz-qtree` works. I think your question is a duplicate of [How do I center this qtree?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44472) which contains a method for solving it.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for pointing this out, this is really a duplicate.